# ZBar qrcode library not working on IOS

Tags: ios, qr-code

I am developing a QR Code reader for Iphone and Ipad. I am using the ZBar library for reading the qr codes. But when I focus on any qr code the application does nothing. I am using code that was given on the zbar site in documentation section. Here is my code:

```
 ZBarReaderViewController *barReader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    barReader.readerDelegate = self;
    [barReader.scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_QRCODE config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:0];
    barReader.readerView.zoom = 1.0;
    barReader.showsCameraControls = NO;
    barReader.showsZBarControls = NO;
    barReader.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
    barReader.title = @"QRCode Reader";
    [self presentModalViewController:barReader animated:YES];
```

And in

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

function i am retrieving the qrcode like this

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    ZBarSymbolSet *symbols = [info objectForKey:ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symb = nil;
    NSString *qrCode = nil;

    for(symb in symbols)
    {
        qrCode = [NSString stringWithString:symb.data];
    }

    NSLog(@"The results = %@",qrCode);

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code is work for me :
.h file

```
        ADD delegate protocol
        < ZBarReaderDelegate >
```

.m file

For Scanning

```
    - (IBAction) scanButtonClick
    {

                ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
                reader.readerDelegate = self;
                reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;
                ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
                // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

                // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
                [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                       config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                           to: 0];

                // present and release the controller
                [self presentModalViewController: reader
                        animated: YES];
                [reader release];
    }
```

fetch/retrive using:

```
    - (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
    {
        // ADD: get the decode results
        id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
        [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
        ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
        for(symbol in results)
            // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
            break;

        // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
        resultText.text = symbol.data;

        // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image
        resultImage.image =
        [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
        [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Why you don't use the ZBarReaderViewDelegate?

```
- (void)readerView:(ZBarReaderView *)view didReadSymbols:(ZBarSymbolSet *)syms fromImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

    for (ZBarSymbol *sym in syms)
    {
        qrCode = [NSString sym.data];
    }

    NSLog(@"The results = %@",qrCode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All symbologies are enabled by default. Your code

```
[barReader.scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_QRCODE config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:0];
```

is setting the symbology `ZBAR_QRCODE`'s config `ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE` to `0 (false)`. That means you are actually disabling the scan of QRCodes.

The Zlib documentation on [disabling unused symbologies](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/optimizing.html#disable-unused-symbologies) explains:

> For example, if you are only interested in QR codes, disable the
>   others. The robust way to do this is by disabling all symbologies and
>   then reenabling only those you want. This helps isolate you from
>   encountering new symbologies that may be added in future versions of
>   the library until you are ready to handle them:

```
// disables all symbologies
[scanner setSymbology: 0
         config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
         to: 0];

// enables QRCode
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_QRCODE
         config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
         to: 1];
```

[Here](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/ZBarSymbol.html?highlight=zbar_symbol_type_t#zbar_symbol_type_t) is a list of the supported symbologies.

SAMIR RATHOD's answer works because only the symbology ZBAR_I25 is being disabled.